# Weird Galaxy/IF Short Story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am almost positive this short story appeared in either Galaxy, IF, or Worlds of Tomorrow in the late 1960s or early 1970s. The MC is an alien with three(?) legs and a bell-like head with a circle of eyes around a mouth in the top of its head. The creature is disgusting - it lives in its own filth and eats its own young. One of the eyes at the top of its head is infected and rotting, so it crushes the eye directly across to even it out. Meeting a human explorer, it invites him back to its sewer of a home, where it already has a number of guests of its own species. Being the host, it offers its young to its guests as treats. The shocked human tries to stop this. The guests are so offended that they eat the MC alive. The strangest SF story I ever read.

The story did not appear in Analog; - there is no way a story as gross as this one would be published there at that time (unless my memory of when I read it is completely off). I think there was an illustration, which leaves out F&SF, which didn't have interior illustrations at the time. Publications could include Amazing and Fantastic, but my father - who bought these magazines - preferred Galaxy and If.

Comment: Makes me think of Aldiss' *The Dark Light Years* though it's almost definitely not a match.

Comment: Not getting to have the kids as snacks.

Comment: It reminds me of my first wife

Comment: My first girlfriend! To clarify: the guests eat the host. I believe there is a moral to this story, considering what was going on in Vietnam at the time. The human explorer, who has no knowledge of local customs, tries to intervene by saving the alien's young from being eaten, leading to disaster for the alien.

Comment: I don't know the story you're asking about, but it reminds me of another story, ["The Ultimate Creature" by R. A. Lafferty](https://archive.org/details/MagazineOfHorror18V03n06196711/page/n41/mode/2up?view=theater).

Comment: This bears some strong resemblance to a story I once read called something difficult to search for like "The Hrssss of Ksthhh". Things that match up include eating young. However the main spider-crab-like character did not invite the human to the event (actually violent contest to determine which creature would be the one to be impregnated). A human was invited by *another* of the creatures, and not necessarily even understanding the consequences, interfered at a pivotal moment to protect that one, and as result the MC crab got all its limbs ripped off by the others, to become a dying egg host

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, I can't recall the correct title, but Hrssss or whatever the correct word is referred to some imposing quality that doesn't map to human language, and Krsthhh or whatever it was, was the name of the MC. I thought this was probably a story  from an Analog, Asimov's SF or F&SF mag from '90s or early aughts, but perhaps it was from earlier and is the same one as the questioner's?

Comment: Dear Jacob: thank you for your response! You certainly seem to remember the details of the story better than I do. Here are some details I should have put in my original question. It did not appear in Analog; - there is no way a story as gross as this one would be published there in the '60s (unless my memory of when I read it is completely off). I think there was an illustration, which leaves out F&SF, which didn't have interior illustrations at the time. Publications could include Amazing and Fantastic, but my father - who bought these magazines - preferred Galaxy and If.

Comment: I've been through the contents pages for all editions of Galaxy, If and Worlds of Tomorrow published from 1960 to 1969, and I haven't found anything that looks like your story. I can go through the magazines page by page to make absolutely sure the story isn't there, but that's a lot of work and I'm reluctant to do it unless you're absolutely sure of the date range.

Comment: Dear John: I'm sorry it has taken me so long to respond, but I suffered a very serious medical crisis that kept me out of touch. Thanks for the effort you put in to help me - I really appreciate it! As for the time frame, I read this story when it was first published - some 60 years ago now! My memory is cloudy. I will continue to search, and thanks again ffor your help